# Problem with \corref instruction in elsarticle document class

Tags: elsarticle, front-matter

In the following TeX file which is written based on elsarticle template, I want the second author (author2) be the corresponding author. I put the \corref instruction for author2 but when I run the code, the \ast symbol appears for both author2 and author3.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newproof{pf}{Proof}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\journal{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{The title of the paper are placed here}


\author{author1}
\ead{author1\_ family@yahoo.com}

\author{author2\corref{cor}}
\ead{author2@yahoo.com}

\author{author3}
\ead{author3@yahoo.com}

\address{The affiliations and adresses}
\cortext[cor]{Corresponding author}

\begin{abstract}
%% Text of abstract
Some text are presented here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
Keyword1 \sep Keyword2 \sep Keyword3

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Introduction goes here.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{Bibiliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a bug in `elsarticle`. If you have three authors with the same address, you can work around the bug by an empty `\corref` statement.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newproof{pf}{Proof}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\journal{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{The title of the paper are placed here}

\author{author1}
\ead{author1\_family@yahoo.com}

\author{author2\corref{cor}}
\ead{author2@yahoo.com}

\author{author3\corref{}}
\ead{author3@yahoo.com}

\address{The affiliations and addresses}

\cortext[cor]{Corresponding author}

\begin{abstract}
%% Text of abstract
Some text are presented here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
Keyword1 \sep Keyword2 \sep Keyword3

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Introduction goes here.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{Bibiliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A few notes. The package `epsfig` only exists for compatibility with older (pre 1992) documents and should not be used in newer documents. The right package to use is `graphicx`. There's no reason for the `compatibility=false` option to `caption`. Instead of `mathptmx` you should consider

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

Comment: If we want to put corresponding author between title and abstract, is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know exactly the *why*, but I figured out the *how*.

The problem seems to be just the ordering of the commands and a better specification for the `\address`.

This should work:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newproof{pf}{Proof}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\journal{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{The title of the paper are placed here}


\author[addr]{author1}
\address[addr]{The affiliations and adresses}
\ead{author1\_ family@yahoo.com}

\author[addr]{author2\corref{cor}}
\cortext[cor]{Corresponding author}

\ead{author2@yahoo.com}

\author[addr]{author3}
\ead{author3@yahoo.com}

\begin{abstract}
%% Text of abstract
Some text are presented here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
Keyword1 \sep Keyword2 \sep Keyword3

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Introduction goes here.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{Bibiliography}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image]

What I modified was:

1. I put the `\cortext` command right after the `\corref`. In your version the `\cortext` was after all the `\author`s.
2. I added the optional argument to the `\address`, that gives sort of a tag to each address, and also moved the `\address` right after the first `\author` that has this address.

In case you need another address, just change the optional argument (between `[]`) of the `\author` macro and add an `\address` entry, like this:

```
\author[addr]{author1}
\address[addr]{The affiliations and adresses}
\ead{author1\_ family@yahoo.com}

\author[addr]{author2\corref{cor}}
\cortext[cor]{Corresponding author}

\ead{author2@yahoo.com}

\author[other]{author3}% <- Another address for this author
\address[other]{Another address}% <- The address right after the author
\ead{author3@yahoo.com}
```