# Elsevier template

Tags: elsarticle

In fact, I am using Elsevier template and I want to tape the email address of the corresponding author the problem is that in :
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author} it gives me all the authors names. I want to get only the mail address of author 1 with no authors names.here is the code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}


\title{Title 1 }



\author{Author1$^*$, Author2, Author3}
\address{address street zip code city}


\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{author1@address.com}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407243/problem-with-corref-instruction-in-elsarticle-document-class might help you.

Comment: In fact here is what I want to get:      Author1*, Author 2, Author3     andin the bottom I want to ger  Corresponding author                               Email address: author1@gmail.com     I do't want to get author1@gmail.com  (Author1)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “taping” an email address.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You need to annotate `\author` statements.

```
\author[ub]{First Author\corref{cor1}}
\author[psy-umr]{Other Second}
\author[a-umr]{Yet Another}
\author[a-umr]{And Another}
\author[d-umr]{Some One-Else}
\author[ub]{Princial Investigator}
\address[ub]{Some Institution}
\address[psy-umr]{Other}
\address[a-umr]{Different Institution}
\address[d-umr]{Last Institution}
\cortext[cor1]{Email: first@example.com}
```

Comment: Thank you but I have two cor symbol I only want only one in the Email

Comment: I should Have no cor symbol before the Email address How can I do it ?

Comment: I'd just put the email into the `\address` tag, `\cortext` is for the special footnote saying "corresponding author", as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `elsarticle` document class, it's advisable to group each `\author` directive with its associated `\address`, `\cortext`, and `\ead` directives (if any). Thus, I'd rewrite your code as follows:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title 1}

\author[a1]{Author1\corref{c1}}
\address[a1]{Address: street, zip code \& city}
\cortext[c1]{Corresponding author}
\ead{author1@address.com}

\author{Author2}
\author{Author3}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...

[image]

Note (i) the addition of the `\corref{c1}` statement in the argument of the first `\author` statement and (ii) the change from

```
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
```

to

```
 \cortext[c1]{Corresponding author}
```